# How to count objects in real time using Tensorflow lite?

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection, counting

Im' new in computer vision. I want to count objects that pass a line in real time, using an Adroid device. I've found some tensorflow APIs for counting objects. But, I don't know to implement it on Android Studio. Is it possible to  implement it?
Here some APIS I've mentioned:
https://github.com/ahmetozlu/tensorflow_object_counting_api
https://github.com/tugot17/YOLO-Object-Counting-API
https://github.com/TannerGilbert/Tensorflow-2-Object-Counting
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66780900/14290681) answer your question?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I need to count using an android device, in real time/or video, but I have problem with tracking objects on android